# How to compute $S$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose $ x_n \ne  1$ for  all  $n$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n= 1.$ Given a  postive  integer $k$  . Compute $$ S=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x_n + x_n^2 +......+x_n^k - k}{x_n-1}$$

My attempt : i know  that $x_n + x_n^2 +......+x_n^k - k= (x_n -1) + (x_n^2-1)+........+(x_n^k-1)$ after that im not able to proceed  further..

Any help

Comment: Hint: $x^2_n-1=(x_n-1)(x_n+1)$ and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=x+x^2+\cdots +x^k$.
Then $$ f'(x)=1+2x+3x^2+\cdots +kx^{k-1}$$
and hence
$$f'(1)= 1+2+3+\cdots + k= \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$
while by the very definition
$$\begin{align}f'(1)=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}&=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x+x^2+\cdots +x^k-k}{x-1}\\
&=\lim_{n\to 1}\frac{x_n+x_n^2+\cdots +x_n^k-k}{x_n-1}\end{align}$$
for any sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n\ne 1$ and $x_n\to 1$.

Answer (score 5):

Notice that
$$x_n^m-1=(x_n-1)(x_n^{m-1}+x_n^{m-2}+...+x_n+1)$$
This implies that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n^m-1}{x_n-1}=m$$
and so your limit is equal to
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n+x_n^2+...+x_n^k-k}{x_n-1}
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(x_n-1)+(x_n^2-1)+...+(x_n^k-1)}{x_n-1} \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n-1}{x_n-1}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n^2-1}{x_n-1}+...+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n^k-1}{x_n-1}\\
&=1+2+...+k\\
&=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}
\end{align}
$$